# Смена очередности ячеек в Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, swift3

Пытаюсь реализовать смену очередности, но вылезли проблемы. При добавлении в @IBAction - self.isEditing = true, по нажатию на кнопку ничего не происходит. В интернете нашел др запись self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true), тэйблВью подключил. При нажатии на кнопку редактирование таблицы открывается, но кнопка в состояние сохранить не возвращается, поэтому отредактированную таблицу не сохранить. В чем проблема?

```
@IBAction func editButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    //self.isEditing = true
    self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {
}

tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
  return true
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В методе вам необходимо реализовать замену объектов из вашего sourceArray, из которого таблица получает данные, друг на друга. Извините, что на Objective-C, но смысл, думаю, ясен.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {
NSMutableArray *sourceArrayCopy = [_sourceArray mutableCopy];
[sourceArrayCopy replaceObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath withObject:sourceArray[destinationIndexPath]];
[sourceArrayCopy replaceObjectAtIndex:destinationIndexPath withObject:sourceArray[sourceIndexPath]];
_sourceArray = sourceArrayCopy;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Если на Swift, то тогда можно использовать следующий код:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
let item = YourItemsArray[sourceIndexPath.row]

YourItemsArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
YourItemsArray.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row) }
```

Comment: Добавил, но изменение таблицы не выключается и название кнопки не меняется

Comment: Смотрите как реализована эта кнопка. Например можно задать в конструкторе:   `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem` , где  var editButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem { get }  - свойство UIViewController.